# Switch between user controls on form, from within other user control

Tags: c#, user-controls

Im writing a code that has a form which contains multiple user-controls in it. I switch between these user controls using a method in the form. Now I want to use that method from within one of the user controls and giving as a parameter one of the forms' user-controls.

```
 public partial class Homescreen : Form
{        
    private Control ActiveUserControl { get; set; }

    public Homescreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //default user control
        this.ActiveUserControl = ucAccount1;
    }

    public void SwitchUserControl(Control controls)
    {
         ActiveUserControl.Visible = false;
         controls.Visible = true;
         this.ActiveUserControl = controls;
    }
    private void pbChat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SwitchUserControl(ucChats1);
    }
 }



public partial class ucChats : UserControl
{
    public ucChats()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btnBekijk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //this is how i imagined it, but obviously doesnt work
         Homescreen.switchusercontrol(Homescreen.ucOtherUserControl);
    }
 }
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: get the Parent and then find the control which you want to access by iterating controls in parent form

Comment: this.Parent.Controls["ghghgj"]

Comment: Never do this, raise an event instead.

Comment: @HansPassant our teacher also suggested events but didnt recommend it because we havent had lessons about those yet.